# SSIS Not Exists In One Data Flow

Tags: ssis, match, lookup, not-exists

I'm trying to achieve the following in SSIS:

Union All 6 separate SQL queries (OLE DB Sources) (call this dataset A)
Dataset A contains

```
id Col A Col B......
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

I have another OLE DB Source SQL query (dataset B) that contains

```
id Col A Col B .......
1
2
3
4
10
11
12
```

All columns Col A, Col B etc. are the same in all the queries.

I want to return dataset A unioned (UNION ALL) with dataset B where the ids in dataset B don't match the ids in dataset A. i.e.

```
id Col A Col B......
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
10
11 
12
```

Also before performing the UNION there is some extra work done on dataset B to fill in NULL values in the columns.

I can achieve this quite easily by inserting dataset A into a table then using this table in a subsequent NOT EXISTS or similar query to get the missing info and then UNIONing together. Ideally though I'd like to do this in one sweep using a dual multicast with one side going into a Lookup No match and the other straight into a destination table.

Unfortunately the Lookup and No Match output returns the 'wrong' missing data i.e. it returns

```
5
6
7
8
```

rather than

```
10
11
12
```

this is because the lookup (dataset B) and source data (dataset A) are the 'wrong way' around. I don't want to rewrite dataset A as the Lookup query so is there another way around this using a different transform or other method?

I've experimented with the Cache Transform but it doesn't seem to work in the same data flow as the Lookup Transform as there is read/write contention.

Thanks,
Rich.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a "Fuller Outer Join" kind of "Merge" component, then a kinda manual merge after the fact. If I misunderstood you, you can always add a Conditional Split after the Merge, to filter if A is null, if B is null, etc.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dC2Hx.png]

An example for the "Merge Columns" is creating a repeated "Id" with this expression: "ISNULL(Id_A) ? Id_B : Id_A"

An example for the "Full Outer Join - Merge": [image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I assumed I could choose the driving dataset in a Lookup and simply use the No Match Output. Your method is great but overkill for my needs. I'll just insert dataset A into a results table and use that results table as part of another query with dataset B and union the 2.